# take picture when clicked on button

Tags: android, camera

I have a requirement like this--
when clicked on an image button in my project, camera should be opened up and take picture, and taken picture should be displayed in a `TextView` or `imageView`

Comment: -1 you are unbelievable man!! you have first asked to open camera..then to show camera on imageview...now in your comment asking to send the image to server, i guess next you will be asking to compare..then to add effects..AND ALL THIS DIRECT CODE?? man don't you think you should try and search on net something..and yes if you can't HIRE ONE DEVELOPER

Comment: Frank: i m agree.Community should stop such people to came here

Comment: go get some cheap programmers from freelancer.com

Answer (score 2):

layout

```
 <ImageView onClik=takePhoto />
```

code

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Editing :** 
for upload this image on server create an HttpConnection and send the byteStream of Iamge  on server . Example is [here](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html)

Comment: Thanks :-) can u pls tell me like the taken picture should be sent to server in binary format.. how to send taken picture to server in binary format??

Comment: Kishore, he did work on your problem and it gave you a solution.Now accept it as answer.It will help you and community also

Comment: check the modified code and accept if it is right answer .

Comment: Thanks bro.. I am very new to android.. thanks for the code and help